# Extract text with iText not works: encoding or crypted text?

Tags: encryption, encoding, character-encoding, itext, text-extraction

I have a pdf file that as the follow security properties: printing: allowed; document assembly: NOT allowed; content copy: allowed; content copy for accessibility: allowed; page extraction:NOT allowed;

I try to get text with sample code as documentation sample as follow:

```
pdftext.Text = null;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filename);
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
    text.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
    text.Append("\n Page Number:" + page);
    text.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
    text.Append(currentText);
    progressBar1.Value++;

    }

pdftext.Text += text.ToString();
pdfReader.Close();
```

but the output text is lines with  ""??? ? ???????\n?? ??? ? " values;

seems that file is crypted or we have a encoding problem...

note that in the follow lines

```
var f = pdfReader.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions; -> FALSE
var f1 = pdfReader.IsEncrypted(); - > FALSE
var f2 = pdfReader.ComputeUserPassword(); - > NULL
var f3 = pdfReader.Is128Key(); - > FALSE
var f4 = pdfReader.HasUsageRights();
```

f, f1, f3, f4 return FALSE ...than seems that the document is not crypted, 
...so I don't know if is a Encoding problem or question related to encrypet strings...

Someone can help me?
thanks in advance.
G.G.

Comment: after invesitgating I discover that the problem is custon enconding. 
The result of pdfinfo was :
Author:         User
Creator:        Compart Docponent API
Producer:       Compart MFFPDF I/O Filter 2013-03-09 00:51:11
CreationDate:   04/21/16 11:26:59
ModDate:        06/09/16 10:02:16
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          6
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.2 x 841.92 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      312703 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.4

Comment: The result of pdffont was (for each fonts): 
name:[none] ; type:Type 3 ; emb:  yes; sub: no; uni : yes;

so the pdf is not encryptde and the presence of ToUnicode table give a chance to extract the text.. but I don't know how...? 

some one can help me?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. Without that we can merely guess. One remark up front, though: There are numerous PDFs out there from which you cannot extract text using generic text extraction code. If your PDF is one of them, it might turn out that nothing short of OCR will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. you can download the pdf here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0f6X4SAMh2KRDJTbm4tb3E1a1U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have trouble extracting text from a document using standard code, the first thing to do is try and copy&paste the text from it using Adobe Acrobat Reader. Adobe Reader copy&paste implements text extraction according to the recommendations of the PDF specification, and if this fails, this usually means that the necessary information required for text extraction in the document are either missing or broken (by accident or by design). To extract the text, one either needs to customize the code specifically to the specific PDF or resort to OCR.

In case of the document at hand, Adobe Reader copy&paste does result in garbage, too, just like when extracting with iText. Thus, there is something fishy in the document.

Inspecting the document one finds that the fonts contain **ToUnicode** mappings like this:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet
findresource begin 12 dict begin begincmap /CIDSystemInfo<</Registry(Adobe)
/Ordering(Identity)
/Supplement 0
>>
def
/CMapName/F18 def
1 begincodespacerange <0000> <FFFF> endcodespacerange
44 beginbfrange
<20> <20> <0020>
<21> <21> <E0F9>
<22> <22> <E0F1>
<23> <23> <E0FA>
<24> <24> <E0F7>
<25> <25> <E0A3>
<26> <26> <E084>
<27> <27> <E097>
<28> <28> <E098>
<29> <29> <E09A>
<2A> <2A> <E08A>
<2B> <2B> <E099>
<2C> <2C> <E0A5>
<2D> <2D> <E086>
<2E> <2E> <E094>
<2F> <2F> <E0DE>
<30> <30> <E0A6>
<31> <31> <E096>
<32> <32> <E088>
<33> <33> <E082>
<34> <34> <E04C>
<35> <35> <E0A4>
<36> <36> <E0F6>
<37> <37> <E0F2>
<38> <38> <E0D8>
<39> <39> <E0AA>
<3A> <3A> <E06C>
<3B> <3B> <E087>
<3C> <3C> <E095>
<3D> <3D> <E0C4>
<3E> <3E> <E07E>
<3F> <3F> <E055>
<40> <40> <E089>
<41> <41> <E085>
<42> <42> <E083>
<43> <43> <E070>
<44> <44> <E0E6>
<45> <45> <E080>
<46> <46> <E0C8>
<47> <47> <E0F4>
<48> <48> <E062>
<49> <49> <E0F3>
<4A> <4A> <E04E>
<4B> <4B> <E05E>
endbfrange
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
```

I.e., if you are not into this, the fonts claim that all their glyphs (with the exception of the space glyph at 0x20) represent characters U+E0xx from the *Unicode private use area*. As the name of that area indicates, there is no common meaning of characters with these values.

Thus, text extraction according to the PDF specification will return strings of characters with undefined meaning with results as you observed in iText or I saw in Adobe Reader.

---

Sometimes in such a situation one can still enforce proper text extraction by ignoring the **ToUnicode** map and using either the font **Encoding** or information inside the embedded font program.

Unfortunately it turns out that here the **Encoding** effectively contains the same information as does the **ToUnicode** map, e.g. for the same font as above

```
/Differences [ 32 /space /uniE0F9 /uniE0F1 /uniE0FA /uniE0F7 /uniE0A3 /uniE084 /uniE097 /uniE098 
/uniE09A /uniE08A /uniE099 /uniE0A5 /uniE086 /uniE094 /uniE0DE /uniE0A6 /uniE096 
/uniE088 /uniE082 /uniE04C /uniE0A4 /uniE0F6 /uniE0F2 /uniE0D8 /uniE0AA /uniE06C 
/uniE087 /uniE095 /uniE0C4 /uniE07E /uniE055 /uniE089 /uniE085 /uniE083 /uniE070 
/uniE0E6 /uniE080 /uniE0C8 /uniE0F4 /uniE062 /uniE0F3 /uniE04E /uniE05E ]
```

and the fonts turns out to be Type3 fonts, i.e. there is no embedded font program but each glyph is defined as an individual PDF canvas without further character information.

Thus, nothing to gain here either.

*Actually these small PDF canvasses contain inlined bitmap graphics of the respective glyph which also is the cause of the poor graphical quality of the document (if you don't see that immediately, simply zoom in a bit and you'll see the ragged outlines of the glyphs).*

By the way, such a construct usually means that the producer of the PDF explicitly wants to prevent text extraction.

---

If you happen to have to extract text from many such documents, you can try and determine a mapping from their U+E0xx characters to actually sensible Unicode characters and apply that mapping to your extracted text.

**If all those fonts in all those documents happen to use the same U+E0xx codepoints for the same actual characters,** you'll be able to do text extraction from those documents after investing a certain amount of initial work.

Otherwise do try OCR.

---

The following code adds pages to a document which map the **ToUnicode** values to the characters shown:

```
void AddFontsTo(PdfReader reader, PdfStamper stamper)
{
    int documentPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
    for (int page = 1; page <= documentPages; page++)
    {
        // ignore inherited resources for now
        PdfDictionary pageResources = reader.GetPageResources(page);
        if (pageResources == null)
            continue;
        PdfDictionary pageFonts = pageResources.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);
        if (pageFonts == null || pageFonts.Size == 0)
            continue;

        List<BaseFont> fonts = new List<BaseFont>();
        List<string> fontNames = new List<string>();
        HashSet<char> chars = new HashSet<char>();
        foreach (PdfName key in pageFonts.Keys)
        {
            PdfIndirectReference fontReference = pageFonts.GetAsIndirectObject(key);
            if (fontReference == null)
                continue;
            DocumentFont font = (DocumentFont) BaseFont.CreateFont((PRIndirectReference)fontReference);
            if (font == null)
                continue;

            PdfObject toUni = PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(font.FontDictionary.Get(PdfName.TOUNICODE));
            CMapToUnicode toUnicodeCmap = null; 
            if (toUni is PRStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] touni = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((PRStream)toUni);
                    CidLocationFromByte lb = new CidLocationFromByte(touni);
                    toUnicodeCmap = new CMapToUnicode();
                    CMapParserEx.ParseCid("", toUnicodeCmap, lb);
                }
                catch
                {
                    toUnicodeCmap = null;
                }
            }
            if (toUnicodeCmap == null)
                continue;
            ICollection<int> mapValues = toUnicodeCmap.CreateDirectMapping().Values;
            if (mapValues.Count == 0)
                continue;

            fonts.Add(font);
            fontNames.Add(key.ToString());

            foreach (int value in mapValues)
                chars.Add((char)value);
        }
        if (fonts.Count == 0 || chars.Count == 0)
            continue;

        Rectangle size = (fonts.Count > 10) ? PageSize.A4.Rotate() : PageSize.A4;

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(fonts.Count + 1);
        table.AddCell("Page " + page);
        foreach (String name in fontNames)
        {
            table.AddCell(name);
        }
        table.HeaderRows = 1;
        float[] widths = new float[fonts.Count + 1];
        widths[0] = 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= fonts.Count; i++)
            widths[i] = 1;
        table.SetWidths(widths);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;

        List<char> charList = new List<char>(chars);
        charList.Sort();
        foreach (char character in charList)
        {
            table.AddCell(((int)character).ToString("X4"));
            foreach (BaseFont font in fonts)
            {
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(character.ToString(), new Font(font))));
            }
        }

        stamper.InsertPage(reader.NumberOfPages + 1, size);
        ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(stamper.GetUnderContent(reader.NumberOfPages));
        columnText.AddElement(table);
        columnText.SetSimpleColumn(size);
        while ((ColumnText.NO_MORE_TEXT & columnText.Go(false)) == 0)
        {
            stamper.InsertPage(reader.NumberOfPages + 1, size);
            columnText.Canvas = stamper.GetUnderContent(reader.NumberOfPages);
            columnText.SetSimpleColumn(size);
        }
    }
}
```

I applied it to your document like this:

```
string input = @"4700198773.pdf";
string output = @"4700198773-fonts.pdf";

using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input))
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
{
    AddFontsTo(reader, stamper);
}
```

The additional pages look like this:

[image: first page of fonts for document page 1]

Now you have to compare the outputs for the different fonts and pages of this document with each other and with those of a representative selection of file. If you find good enough a pattern, you can try this replacement way.

Comment: sorry for the late response and Thanks very much for your answer. Can you help me about how to try and determine a mapping from their U+E0xx characters to actually sensible Unicode characters and apply that mapping to the extracted text? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not trivial. I'll try and create something but it'll take some time.

Comment: thanks a lot for your patient mkl... I run that code to other "corrupt" pdf and the result was that no additional page added.. ..cause that pdf haven't fonts map..  (I opened that document in Adobe -> properties -> fonts and no fonts info are shown ) ..so I think I can't have anything from this hole...

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm afraid there are too many ways to make the text from a PDF non-extractable using the standard algorithm... If the PDFs are from the same source, there usually is a chance that one can find a hack that works, but beyond that...

Comment: "Sometimes in such a situation one can still enforce proper text extraction by ignoring the ToUnicode map [...]" would you also have an example how to do that with iText?

Comment: @sschuberth In the sample code in my answer you see the **ToUnicode** table being retrieved using `font.FontDictionary.Get(PdfName.TOUNICODE)`. You should instead be able to remove it using `font.FontDictionary.Put(PdfName.TOUNICODE, null)`.

Comment: @mkl Thanks, I'll give that a try. FYI, [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6413030/pb.pdf) is the PDF I need to extract text from. Based on the comment in [this code](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/commit/eaf8243ffcb9317430611fe10e5cf90880915e9d) I assume I can get the extracted text right by ignoring the `ToUnicode` mapping.

Comment: @sschuberth Indeed, in case of your PDF text extraction succeeds by ignoring the **ToUnicode** tables, cf. my Java test method [TextExtraction.testPbNoToUnicode()](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/TextExtraction.java#L224). But I don't think it is a good idea to always ignore the **ToUnicode** tables of non-embedded fonts, in other cases these tables may be your only chance to properly extract the text.

Comment: @mkl Thanks again for your help and insights!