# Extract text with iText with embedded fonts

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, text-extraction

I am trying to use iTextSharp (v5.5.12.1) to extract the text from the following PDF:
https://structure.mil.ru/files/morf/military/files/ENGV_1929.pdf

Unfortunately, it seems like they are using a number of embedded custom fonts, which are defeating me.

For now, I have a working solution using OCR, but the OCR can be imprecise, reading some characters wrongly and also adding additional spaces between characters.  It would be ideal if I could extract the text directly.

```
public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(Stream pdfStream, bool addNewLineBetweenPages = false)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream))
    {
        string text = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
            if (addNewLineBetweenPages && i != reader.NumberOfPages)
            {
                text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mkl I have read your answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748346/extract-text-with-itext-not-works-encoding-or-crypted-text> and I suspect that my situation might be somewhat similar. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply said, the fonts in your file do not provide the information required for text extraction as described in the PDF specification. Neither do they contain **ToUnicode** maps nor do they use a standard named encoding or standard glyph names in the **Encoding** **Differences**. Furthermore, even the embedded font programs don't contain mappings to Unicode..Thus, standard text extraction as in iText (or Adobe Reader copy&paste) as is won't help you. If the non-standard glyph names happen to be consistent, though, one might possibly be able to tweak iText to extract the text.

Comment: @mkl many thanks for your response. Completely agree with everything you have said. I was hoping there might have been something I had missed. 

In my mind, if a PDF viewer can display the pdf then surely it must be possible to extract the text, somehow....

I have been experimenting with taking the characters as they are read by itext and replacing them with what I think they should be. However, so far no luck. One thing that worries me is the first three characters are u0001, u0002, u0003.

Comment: *"In my mind, if a PDF viewer can display the pdf then surely it must be possible to extract the text, somehow"* - unfortunately those are two entirely different things. For displaying the viewer merely needs to be able to map from character code in the pdf to a set of drawing instructions in the embedded font program, and this mapping does not need to be related to a unicode code (one could use for text extraction) at all. Next week I'll try and see, though, whether there is a way nonetheless as the mapping is not without system.

Comment: @mkl many thanks. Fingers crossed that you can find the system. I tried what seemed obvious to me but it didn't work.

Comment: I had a look at the glypg names in the embedded fonts. There is a scheme to them, but that scheme is broken in some positions by some of the fonts. So, I could do something, but the output would still have errors here and there. Latin letters and Arabic digits mostly are used consequentially, but Cyrillic and other special characters have deviations here and there. Would a "mostly correct" text extraction help you?

Comment: Have you meanwhile tried the code from my answer? Does it help?

Comment: @mkl many thanks for your answer. I will give it a go this week and report back! Thanks again!

Comment: @mkl that is working great, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the glyphs in the embedded font programs have non-standard glyph names (**G00**, **G01**, ...) and are identified only by glyph name. Thus, one has to establish a mapping from these glyph names to Unicode characters. One can do so e.g. by inspecting the fonts programs in the PDF (for example with font forge) and visually recognizing the glyphs by name. E.g. like here

[image: AHMHDG+MSTT31c31400]

(As you can recognize, there are some gaps for glyphs of the font in question which are not used in the document at hand. Some missing glyphs you can guess, some not.)

Then you have to inject these mappings into iText. As the mappings are hidden (`private static` members of the `GlyphList` class), you either have to patch iText itself or use reflection:

```
void InitializeGlyphs()
{
    FieldInfo names2unicodeFiled = typeof(GlyphList).GetField("names2unicode", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    Dictionary<string, int[]> names2unicode = (Dictionary<string, int[]>) names2unicodeFiled.GetValue(null);
    names2unicode["G03"] = new int[] { ' ' };

    names2unicode["G0A"] = new int[] { '\'' };
    names2unicode["G0B"] = new int[] { '(' };
    names2unicode["G0C"] = new int[] { ')' };

    names2unicode["G0F"] = new int[] { ',' };
    names2unicode["G10"] = new int[] { '-' };
    names2unicode["G11"] = new int[] { '.' };
    names2unicode["G12"] = new int[] { '/' };
    names2unicode["G13"] = new int[] { '0' };
    names2unicode["G14"] = new int[] { '1' };
    names2unicode["G15"] = new int[] { '2' };
    names2unicode["G16"] = new int[] { '3' };
    names2unicode["G17"] = new int[] { '4' };
    names2unicode["G18"] = new int[] { '5' };
    names2unicode["G19"] = new int[] { '6' };
    names2unicode["G1A"] = new int[] { '7' };
    names2unicode["G1B"] = new int[] { '8' };
    names2unicode["G1C"] = new int[] { '9' };
    names2unicode["G1D"] = new int[] { ':' };

    names2unicode["G23"] = new int[] { '@' };
    names2unicode["G24"] = new int[] { 'A' };
    names2unicode["G25"] = new int[] { 'B' };
    names2unicode["G26"] = new int[] { 'C' };
    names2unicode["G27"] = new int[] { 'D' };
    names2unicode["G28"] = new int[] { 'E' };
    names2unicode["G29"] = new int[] { 'F' };
    names2unicode["G2A"] = new int[] { 'G' };
    names2unicode["G2B"] = new int[] { 'H' };
    names2unicode["G2C"] = new int[] { 'I' };
    names2unicode["G2D"] = new int[] { 'J' };
    names2unicode["G2E"] = new int[] { 'K' };
    names2unicode["G2F"] = new int[] { 'L' };
    names2unicode["G30"] = new int[] { 'M' };
    names2unicode["G31"] = new int[] { 'N' };
    names2unicode["G32"] = new int[] { 'O' };
    names2unicode["G33"] = new int[] { 'P' };
    names2unicode["G34"] = new int[] { 'Q' };
    names2unicode["G35"] = new int[] { 'R' };
    names2unicode["G36"] = new int[] { 'S' };
    names2unicode["G37"] = new int[] { 'T' };
    names2unicode["G38"] = new int[] { 'U' };
    names2unicode["G39"] = new int[] { 'V' };
    names2unicode["G3A"] = new int[] { 'W' };
    names2unicode["G3B"] = new int[] { 'X' };
    names2unicode["G3C"] = new int[] { 'Y' };
    names2unicode["G3D"] = new int[] { 'Z' };

    names2unicode["G42"] = new int[] { '_' };

    names2unicode["G44"] = new int[] { 'a' };
    names2unicode["G45"] = new int[] { 'b' };
    names2unicode["G46"] = new int[] { 'c' };
    names2unicode["G46._"] = new int[] { 'c' };
    names2unicode["G47"] = new int[] { 'd' };
    names2unicode["G48"] = new int[] { 'e' };
    names2unicode["G49"] = new int[] { 'f' };
    names2unicode["G4A"] = new int[] { 'g' };
    names2unicode["G4B"] = new int[] { 'h' };
    names2unicode["G4C"] = new int[] { 'i' };
    names2unicode["G4D"] = new int[] { 'j' };
    names2unicode["G4E"] = new int[] { 'k' };
    names2unicode["G4F"] = new int[] { 'l' };
    names2unicode["G50"] = new int[] { 'm' };
    names2unicode["G51"] = new int[] { 'n' };
    names2unicode["G52"] = new int[] { 'o' };
    names2unicode["G53"] = new int[] { 'p' };
    names2unicode["G54"] = new int[] { 'q' };
    names2unicode["G55"] = new int[] { 'r' };
    names2unicode["G56"] = new int[] { 's' };
    names2unicode["G57"] = new int[] { 't' };
    names2unicode["G58"] = new int[] { 'u' };
    names2unicode["G59"] = new int[] { 'v' };
    names2unicode["G5A"] = new int[] { 'w' };
    names2unicode["G5B"] = new int[] { 'x' };
    names2unicode["G5C"] = new int[] { 'y' };
    names2unicode["G5D"] = new int[] { 'z' };

    names2unicode["G62"] = new int[] { 'Ш' };
    names2unicode["G63"] = new int[] { 'Р' };
    names2unicode["G6A"] = new int[] { 'И' };
    names2unicode["G6B"] = new int[] { 'А' };
    names2unicode["G6C"] = new int[] { 'М' };
    names2unicode["G6D"] = new int[] { 'в' };
    names2unicode["G6E"] = new int[] { 'Ф' };
    names2unicode["G70"] = new int[] { 'Е' };
    names2unicode["G72"] = new int[] { 'Б' };
    names2unicode["G73"] = new int[] { 'Н' };
    names2unicode["G76"] = new int[] { 'С' };
    names2unicode["G7A"] = new int[] { 'К' };
    names2unicode["G7B"] = new int[] { 'В' };
    names2unicode["G7C"] = new int[] { 'О' };
    names2unicode["G7D"] = new int[] { 'к' };
    names2unicode["G7E"] = new int[] { 'З' };
    names2unicode["G80"] = new int[] { 'Г' };
    names2unicode["G81"] = new int[] { 'П' };
    names2unicode["G82"] = new int[] { 'у' };
    names2unicode["G85"] = new int[] { '»' };
    names2unicode["G88"] = new int[] { 'т' };
    names2unicode["G8D"] = new int[] { '’' };
    names2unicode["G90"] = new int[] { 'У' };
    names2unicode["G91"] = new int[] { 'Т' };
    names2unicode["GA1"] = new int[] { 'Ц' };
    names2unicode["GA2"] = new int[] { '№' };
    names2unicode["GAA"] = new int[] { 'э' };
    names2unicode["GAB"] = new int[] { 'я' };
    names2unicode["GAC"] = new int[] { 'і' };
    names2unicode["GAD"] = new int[] { 'б' };
    names2unicode["GAE"] = new int[] { 'й' };
    names2unicode["GAF"] = new int[] { 'р' };
    names2unicode["GB0"] = new int[] { 'с' };
    names2unicode["GB2"] = new int[] { 'х' };
    names2unicode["GB5"] = new int[] { '“' };
    names2unicode["GB9"] = new int[] { 'п' };
    names2unicode["GBA"] = new int[] { 'о' };
    names2unicode["GBD"] = new int[] { '«' };
    names2unicode["GC1"] = new int[] { 'ф' };
    names2unicode["GC8"] = new int[] { 'а' };
    names2unicode["GCB"] = new int[] { 'е' };
    names2unicode["GCE"] = new int[] { 'ж' };
    names2unicode["GCF"] = new int[] { 'з' };
    names2unicode["GD2"] = new int[] { 'и' };
    names2unicode["GD3"] = new int[] { 'н' };
    names2unicode["GDC"] = new int[] { '–' };
    names2unicode["GE3"] = new int[] { 'л' };
}
```

After executing that method you can extract the text using your method:

```
InitializeGlyphs();

using (FileStream pdfStream = new FileStream(@"ENGV_1929.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    string result = ExtractTextFromPdf(pdfStream, true);
    File.WriteAllText(@"ENGV_1929.txt", result);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nENGV_1929.pdf\n");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The result:

```
From Notices to Mariners
Edition No 29/2019
(English version)
Notiсes to Mariners from Seсtion II «Сharts Сorreсtion», based on the original sourсe information, and
NAVAREA XIII, XX and XXI navigational warnings are reprinted hereunder in English. Original Notiсes to
Mariners from Seсtion I «Misсellaneous Navigational Information» and from Seсtion III «Nautiсal
Publiсations Сorreсtion» may be only briefly annotated and/or a referenсe may be made to Notiсes from
other Seсtions. Information from Seсtion IV «Сatalogues of Сharts and Nautiсal Publiсations Сorreсtion»
сonсerning the issue of сharts and publiсations is presented with details.
Digital analogue of English version of the extracts from original Russian Notices to Mariners is available
by: http://structure.mil.ru/structure/forces/hydrographic/info/notices.htm
СНАRTS СОRRЕСTIОN
Вarents Sea
 3493 Сharts 18012, 17052, 15005, 15004
Amend 1. Light to light Fl G 4s 1M at
 front leading lightbeacon 69111’32.2“N 33129’48.0“E
 2. Light to light Fl G 4s 1M at
 rear leading lightbeacon 69111’34.85“N 33129’44.25“E
 Cancel coastal warning
 MURMANSK 71/19
...
```

Beware, you will see that quite often instead of a Latin character a similar looking Cyrillic character is used. Apparently the document was created manually by someone who didn't consider typographical correctness very important..

So, if you want to search in the text, you should first normalize the text and your search terms  (e.g. use the same character for the Latin 'c' and the Cyrillic 'с').

Comment: one issue I have found is where they have reused the same code for different characters. The main one I am looking at is G14, which they have used for the character 1 and also the degrees symbol. This is shown in your result: 69111’32.2“N. The first 1 should be °. Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Hhmmm, I indeed did not spot that. So, the mappings may differ from font to font... well, you could change the `names2unicode` mapping each time a different font is used. For that you can register an extended version of the `SetTextFont` content operator which depending on the font in question also changes the `names2unicode` mapping. Or you can consider building **ToUnicode** maps for the fonts and add them to the fonts before using the standard classes for text extraction. Either way, complexity of the solution rises... ;)

Comment: thanks again. I thought there must be a way to do it, but as you said the complexity rises. For now, I have used Regex to identify coordinates and then replace the 1 with the degrees character. It is working well enough for now.